# What's the proper method for connecting a parallel LCD display to an RPi 3?

Tags: display, dsi, lcd

I'm attempting to interface [this display](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/newhaven-display-intl/NHD-0216K1Z-NSPG-FBW/NHD-0216K1Z-NSPG-FBW-ND/4214790) to a Raspberry Pi 3. The data sheet outlines a relatively simple parallel interface in which you can write to the display.

For those familiar with the Raspberry Pi 3, what would be the best method for implementing this parallel interface?

I've used the GPIO and SPI capabilities of the RPi in the past. I assume I could use an SPI GPIO expansion chip to write parallel words out to interface, but are there better methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a HD44780 device to me, a standard LCD parallel display which needs multiple GPIO (probably 8 if driven in 4 bit mode).

See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HelloWorld as an example interface.

SPI would not be suitiable.

Comment: This may be a better example since it is specific to the PI https://learn.adafruit.com/drive-a-16x2-lcd-directly-with-a-raspberry-pi/overview

Comment: That's a good resource, and I see. Sounds like GPIO is the way to go. I had mentioned SPI in the sense that I would be using an GPIO expansion chip via SPI.